# Make specific columns stretch the pages height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make two specific columns in the layout below, stretch the entire page height, unless their on mobile (tablet they can still stretch as most tablets are 720.

```
   <div class="rows">
     <div class="col-md-1">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1">
     </div>
    </div>
```

`col-md-1`, right now only stretches as far as the content you put in it stretches, how ever I would like, on anything higher then 720 for it to stretch the pages full height, that is they should stretch down to the footer and then on anything smaller then 720 they should just be regular height boxes, that is "stretch to fit their contents"

How could I achieve this with out breaking default bootstrap behaviour to much.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your HTML add a new class to the div(s) that you want to increase to page height

2) In your CSS, use @media-screen with a minimum width of 720px so that you're only specifying this for non-mobile devices, and within the new class specify min-height as 100%. See below..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px){
.new-class {
    min-height:100%; }}
```